# Python logging can't change log level of root logger

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to change the log level of the root logger. It appears to change when queried with `getEffectiveLevel()` but doesn't actually log anything different than it did before the change.

For example:

```
>>> import logging
>>> root_logger = logging.getLogger()
>>> root_logger.getEffectiveLevel()
30
>>> root_logger.warning('test')
test
>>> root_logger.info('test')
>>> root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> root_logger.getEffectiveLevel()
10
>>> root_logger.warning('test')
test
>>> root_logger.info('test')
>>> root_logger.debug('test')
```

Why is this? Am I missing something else I need to do? It puzzles me that I can set the level and see it with `getEffectiveLevel` but that it doesn't change the behavior at all.

I am using the built in logging module (version 0.5.1.2) on Python 3.7.3.

Comment: You likely also need to adjust the handler level, and maybe something else I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't configured any handlers for the logger (or the logging system at all).

This means that, based on [the code here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba18c0b13ba3c08077ea3db6658328523823a33f/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1672-L1679), `logging` defaults to [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba18c0b13ba3c08077ea3db6658328523823a33f/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1221-L1222) last-resort logger, which is a stderr logger with the `WARNING` threshold, and as such, it doesn't handle those debug messages.

Comment: I understand how it resolved the default logging handler. What confuses me is why `setLevel` didn't change the level, even though `getEffectiveLevel` says it has been changed. Do I need to get the default handler from `root_logger` and then change the level of the default handler?

Comment: With your example, `root_logger.handlers` will yield `[]`. There _are_ no handlers configured, but the `logging` module has a last-resort handler (see the linked code!) so critical messages don't get completely lost.

Comment: Use e.g. `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)` to configure a non-last-resort handler on the root logger.

Comment: Do you know why `getEffectiveLevel` is reporting the set level? It seems like even if I rely on a last-resort handler, `setLevel` should set the log level like you'd expect.  `getEffectiveLevel` and `setLevel` agree, but the last-resort handler appears to not behave accordingly.

Comment: The _logger_ itself is configured to that level -- try setting it to a higher level, e.g. `root_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)` and emitting a warning; the warning will not be emitted as the logger filters it out. Handlers have their own level filter settings; you might want an email-sending handler to only handle error messages, but be attached to the root logger anyway.